# Show that $x^{n-1} =1$ for all non-zero element in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, field-theory

> Question:
>
> Show that $x^{n-1} =1$ for all non-zero element in a field

Let F be a finite field of order n.
Show that $x^{n-1}=1$ for all non-zero $x \in F$.

We have $\left | F \right |=n.$

> Recall that a field is an integral domain in which every non-zero element is a unit.
>
> Recall that a unit in a ring is an element in the ring with a multiplicative inverse in R.
>
> Recall that an integral domain is a commutative ring with unity containing no non-zero divisor.

Suppose $\left [ x\neq 0 \right ]\in F$, then, by definition of a field F, $\exists y \in F$ s.t $x\cdot y=1$

Note that $x\cdot y=1 \in F$.

Can someone drop a hint to take me further? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's theorem ?

Comment: Yes. Is that your hint?

Comment: I do not. @Joanpemo

Comment: @Mathematicing Yes, I just realized back then we don't need that here. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\;F\;$ is a field $\;\implies F^*=F\setminus\{0\}\;$ is a multiplicative group of order

$$\;|F|-1=n-1\;\implies\;\forall\,x\in F^*\;,\;\;x^{n-1}=1$$

since in a finite group it is *always* true that the order of any element divides the order of the group (as commented, this is Lagrange's Theorem)

Comment: The n-1 is a bit hard to figure out why.

Comment: @Mathematicing Really? You said $\;|F|=n\;$ , so then $\;|F^*|=|F\setminus\{0\}|=n-1\;$ ...I think it is trivial.

Comment: I noted the poster's comment above and realised.

Answer (score 1):

$F\setminus \{0\}$ is a finite group with identity element $1$, which has ...(?) elements. Now use [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).

Comment: I hope this question isn't silly: When you say F is a group, is it a group by virtual of the fact that if forms an Abelian group under addition?

Comment: @Mathematicing - when people refer to $F \setminus \{0\}$, it is usually to the multiplicative abelian group formed by $\times$ with identity $1$

Comment: @Mathematicing ....under multiplication

Comment: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)). it has: "In mathematics, a field is one of the fundamental algebraic structures used in abstract algebra. It is a nonzero commutative division ring, or equivalently a ring whose nonzero elements form an *abelian group* **under multiplication**"

Comment: @user1 Thank you for the heads up. It appears I misinterpreted the definition of commutative ring-requiring only . to be commutative.
Cleaning things up, you are right that a field is an abelian group under multiplication and addition.

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: @user1 The n-1 order is slightly obscure to me. F is a finite field containing no 0 to begin with so why do we subtract the element 0? Might be overthinking this one.

Comment: in the link above: "...a ring whose **nonzero elements** *form an abelian group under multiplication*"

Comment: So let $F^{\ast}$ denote the ring whose non-zero element form an abelian group under multiplication and addition. The field F has order n. We are interested only in the$ F^{*}$ so n-1.
By Lagrange's theorem, the order of an element in F^{*} divides the order of F^{*}. Each element in F^{*} raised to the order of F^{*} is the identity element 1

Comment: your last comment has not good format. BTW see [Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) of Lagrange's theorem

Comment: what about acceptation?